# 535 Ways to Reload the page with JavaScript - what are the consequences?

Tags: javascript, reload

Someone has listed 535 different ways to reload a page in Javascript:

http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html

For example:

```
location = location
location = location.href
location = window.location
location = self.location
location = window.location.href
location = self.location.href
location = location['href']
location = window['location']
location = window['location'].href
location = window['location']['href']
location = window.location['href']
location = self['location']
location = self['location'].href
location = self['location']['href']
location = self.location['href']
location.assign(location)
location.replace(location)
window.location.assign(location)
window.location.replace(location)
self.location.assign(location)
self.location.replace(location)
location['assign'](location)
window.location['assign'](location)
self['location'].assign(location)
self['location']['assign'](location)
self['location']['replace'](location)
location.href = location
location.href = self.location
location.href = window.location.href
```

I'm curious if anyone knows how these are treated differently on the browser - whether one refreshes the page but busts cache - or not as the case may be?

Comment: it looks as though the majority of the ways involve: directly changing `location`, using `location.assign`, `location.replace` and `location.reload`. The rest are just duplicate ways of accessing the same values.

Comment: More like 3 ways obfuscated 535 times

Comment: Use the standard window.location.reload() if you want it to work in all browsers.

Comment: He forgot location=document.documentURI

Comment: I stumbled upon this question while researching a chromium bug, and I can safely say that `location.reload(1);` and `window.location.replace(location);` don't run through the same codepath in that browser: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280460#c11    

Some answer here mentioned it may have to do with form [re]submission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All those examples are treated the same by the browser.

In fact, most of them are just different ways of accessing a variable in Javascript. You could probably write a similar list with "XXX different ways of assigning a global variable the value of another global variable".

For example: `location.href, window.location.href, self.location.href, location['href'], window.location['href'], self.location['href']` are all pointing to the exact same value.

**In the list you posted, the only two really different ways are these**:

```
location = location //assign the whole location object to the location global variable
location = location.href //assign the string location.href to the location global variable
```

Comment: In the examples he posted, none of the ways actually reload the page if the location has a hash. On the linked page are things like `location.reload()` though which reload the page regardless.

Comment: is there a way to reload the page without actually downloading it again? like a reset?

Answer (score 6):

`location.reload()` acts like a form submit (i.e. it passes all the form values)